# "Cannot send an empty message"

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am working on a bot with Node.js but I dont know why , I keep getting this error.

```
(node:999) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
```

I tried to fix it but I cant fix it

Here is my codes (furderen.txt is not empty)

```js
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs')

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});
var data = fs.readFileSync("furderen.txt", "utf8");

//note this will be async
function getRandomLine(filename){
  fs.readFileSync("furderen.txt", "utf8")
  var lines = data.split('\n');
  /*do something with */ lines[Math.floor(Math.random()*lines.length)];
}

client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.content === '!hesap') {
    var hesap = getRandomLine("furderen.txt")
    client.users.cache.get(message.author.id).send(hesap);
  }
})

client.login(I wont put it here :p)
```

Comment: `hesap` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is scattered with unnecessary and wrong parts. I summarized this and reproduced it with minimal code. The point is that `getRandomLine` does not return value.

```js
const fs = require('fs')

function getRandomLine(filename){
  var data = fs.readFileSync(filename, "utf8");
  var lines = data.split('\n');
  /*do something with */
  return lines[Math.floor(Math.random()*lines.length)];
}

var hesap = getRandomLine("furderen.txt");
console.log(hesap);
```